# JAVA two-dimensional array code

Tags: java, arrays

I want to write a program that creates a two-dimensional int array initialized with test data.
  The program cannot run. I am confused about the code.Please help with the problem.How to correct my code? Thank you.

```
    public class Int2DArray {

        private static int x;
        private static int y;





        public static int getTotal(int[][] numbers) {
            int total = 0;
            for (int x = 0; x < numbers.length; x++);
            for (int y = 0; y < numbers[x].length; y++);
            total = total + numbers[x][y];
            return total;
        }

        public static double getAverage(int[][] numbers) {
            double average = 0;
            average = getTotal(numbers) / (x + y);
            return average;
        }

        public static int getRowTotal(int[][] numbers, int index) {
            int total = 0;
            for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
                total = total + numbers[index][y];
            }
            return total;
        }

        public static int getColumnTotal(int[][] numbers, int index) {
            int total = 0;
            for (int x = 0; x < numbers.length; x++) {
                total = total + numbers[x][index];
            }
            return total;
        }

        public static int getHighestInRow(int[][] numbers, int x) {
            int high = numbers[x][0];
            for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
                if (numbers[x][i] > high) {
                    high = numbers[x][i];
                }
            }
            return high;
        }

        public static int getLowestInRow(int[][] numbers, int x) {
            int low = numbers[x][0];
            for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
                if (numbers[x][i] < low) {
                    low = numbers[x][i];
                }
            }
            return low;
        }


    }
  public class Int2DArrayTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] iarray = {{2, 1, 9}, {7, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 8}};
        System.out.println("Total:" + getTotal(iarray));
        System.out.println("Average:" + getAverage(iarray));
        System.out.println("Total of row 0" + getRowTotal(iarray, 0));
        System.out.println("Total of row 1" + getRowTotal(iarray, 1));
        System.out.println("Total of row 2" + getRowTotal(iarray, 2));
        System.out.println("Total of col 0" + getColumnTotal(iarray, 0));
        System.out.println("Total of col 1" + getColumnTotal(iarray, 1));
        System.out.println("Total of col 2" + getColumnTotal(iarray, 2));
        System.out.println("Highest in row 0" + getHighestInRow(iarray, 0));
        System.out.println("Highest in row 1" + getHighestInRow(iarray, 1));
        System.out.println("Highest in row 2" + getHighestInRow(iarray, 2));
        System.out.println("Lowest in row 0" + getLowestInRow(iarray, 0));
        System.out.println("Lowest in row 1" + getLowestInRow(iarray, 1));
        System.out.println("Lowest in row 2" + getLowestInRow(iarray, 2));
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have compile or logical error?

Comment: Also check your `getTotal` method, specially the semi colons after each for.

Comment: you have also division by 0 in getAverage (x,y is not initialized)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see one big error:

you can resolve it so:

```
public static int getTotal(int[][] numbers) {
            int total = 0;
            for (int x = 0; x < numbers.length; x++);
            for (int y = 0; y < numbers[x].length; y++);
            total = total + numbers[x][y];
            return total;
        }
```

replace for

```
      public static int getTotal(int[][] numbers) { 
            int total = 0;
            for (int x = 0; x < numbers.length; x++){
               for (int y = 0; y < numbers[x].length; y++){
                  total = total + numbers[x][y];
              }
            }
            return total;
        }
```

or better so(using foreach):

```
public static int getTotal(int[][] numbers) {
        int total = 0;
        for (int [] x : numbers){
            for (int y : x){
                total = total + y;
            }
        }
        return total;
    }
```

And use formatting hotkey in your IDE.

---

```
public static int getRowTotal(int[][] numbers, int index) {
            int total = 0;
            for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
                total = total + numbers[index][y];
            }
            return total;
        }
```

here you use constant 3 - it is bad style you need to extract it as constant

---

```
public static double getAverage(int[][] numbers) {
            double average = 0;
            average = getTotal(numbers) / (x + y);
            return average;
        }
```

1. x and  y are not initialized in your code
2. why do you divide by `x+y`.  You need divide on count of element.

Answer (score 2):

You have declared the methods inside `Int2DArray` as static

```
public static int getTotal(int[][] numbers) { //
```

So you need to call them as static in order to use them like:

```
System.out.println("Total:" + Int2DArray.getTotal(iarray));
```

Comment: Thank you.Now I know how to use the methods.

Answer (score 0):

You are having following line twice, so an obvious syntactical error.

```
 public class Int2DArrayTest {
```

Moreover, you also have logical error in getAverage function.

```
average = getTotal(numbers) / (x + y);
```

It shows divide by zero exception.